# Number of $1$'s in a generator matrix?

Tags: coding-theory

Let $G$ be a generator matrix of an $[n,k,d]$ code. Then $G$ has atleast $kd$ many $1's$ in it.

---

Please give me some hint.

Comment: Hint: Each row of a generator matrix is a codeword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the code $\mathcal{C}$ is an $[n,k,d]$ code. Any code-word in $\mathcal{C}$ has atleast $d$ many $1$'s in it.

1. Each row of the generator matrix is a code-word $\implies$ Each row has $d$ many nonzero entries.
2. The generator matrix has $k$ rows.

Hence the generator matrix has atleast $kd$ non-zero entries.

Comment: You can accept your answer so that the question does not remain in the unanswered queue.